# How to make maven install in docker container

Tags: java, docker, maven, dockerfile

I have a multi-module project on maven. It is quite ancient and is going with a special dance with a tambourine.

Project structure

```
root
  |__api
  |__build
  |__flash
  |__gwt
  |__server
  |__service
  |__shared
  |__target
  |__toolset
```

To build such a project, I have a special script that needs to be executed while at the root of the project.

```
./build/build_and_deploy.sh
```

When building on Windows, there are a lot of problems (problems with long paths, symbols and line separators get lost, etc.), so I want to build this project in docker.
At first I wanted to connect **docker-maven-plugin** from **io.fabric8** as a plugin in maven, but as I understand it, it cannot run the build of itself in docker.

So I tried to write **Dockerfile** and ran into the following problems
I don't want to copy the .m2 folder to docker, there are a lot of dependencies there, it will be quite a long time.
I don't want to copy the project sources inside the container
I couldn't run the script./build/build_and_deploy.sh

How I see the solution to this problem.

1. Create a dockerfile, connect maven and java8 to it, and bash
2. Using Volume to connect the sources and maven repository
3. Because I work through VPN and the script is deployed, you need to find a solution to the problem through it (proxy/port forwarding???)

If you have experience or examples of a similar script or competent advice, then I will be glad to hear it

Comment: If your build script doesn't work in Windows, there are tools like Vagrant that can help you set up a Linux VM you can use.  You can probably make the setup you describe work but as you note it's a little bit different from the way Docker is designed to be used.  There are also pretty routinely SO questions on "Docker bind-mounts don't update" and "VPN connectivity doesn't work from inside a container".  I might either fix the build script or use a more Unixy system (Linux or MacOS) for development.

Comment: @DavidMaze Putting a full-fledged virtual machine sounds too loaded. If you have the opportunity to take a closer look, then I will be glad to contact you

Comment: @WBLord did you try multi-stage build? That should help you build inside a docker container. Regarding .m2 dependencies, you can't mount host path in multi-stage build. Instead you can configure maven settings in such a way that it points to your organization repository.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the build with Maven inside Docker.
For that you basically trigger something like `docker build .`, and the rest is inside the Dockerfile.

Start off from a container that has Maven, such as [maven](https://hub.docker.com/_/maven).
Add your whole project structure
Run your build script
Save your build result

To save your build result, you might want to upload it to some repository, or store it in a mounted volume that is available after the container run as well. Alternatively copy it to the next stage if you use a multistage docker build.

If you want to prevent repeated downloads of the .m2 directory or have many other dependencies in there, also mount it as volume when running the container.